# How to insert multiple rows in php with for each loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am uploading multiple files with input box. I want to add that files in multiple rows with different id in mysql table.But its now working for me.

```
$paye_path=$obj->uploadMultiplePDF($_FILES['paye_inv'],$com_name);
```

above code works fine `uploadMultiplePDF` function is working for me.files are goes into my folder.

After this i am calling my insert function:

```
$query  = $obj->insert_pay_slip_data($paye_path,$com_name);
```

it not working for me. this shows me below error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

Below is my insert query where i am using foreach loop:

```
public function insert_pay_slip_data($data,$com_name)
            {

                $con = $this->__construct();
                $shareArray = array();
                foreach($data as $shK=>$shVal)
                    {
                        $shareArray[$shK] = $shVal; 
                    } 
                 foreach ($shareArray as $keyshar => $valueshar) 
                 {  
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `pay_slips`(`paye_id`, `trade_id`, `inv_pdf`, `created_date`, 
                    `created_by`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$com_name."','".$valueshar['paye_path']."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."')";
                    $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    return $execute;
                }
            }
```

> In `inv_pdf` column file name should be come. and if i upload 5 files
>   then 5 different rows should be created in table. But its not working.
>   I might be wrong in foreach loop.

Comment: You supplied an invalid argument to foreach.  var_dump($data) can help you to know if $data is not empty

Comment: data is inserting now. but format is wrong. all files are going into same row with comma seperated. i want different rows

Comment: on print_r its shows data like this `Array ( [0] => 1587701784152949112515934afa38db134c80f2444e07734a3f.pdf,21226947371529491125169512017.pdf )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before passing value to **foreach** you need to make sure type of value is **Array**

```
if(is_array($value)){
   foreach($value as $key => $val){
      // Your code
   }
}else{
   // Do nothing
}
```

To insert You can use this code

```
public function insert_pay_slip_data($data,$com_name){
   $con = $this->__construct();
   $shareArray = array();
   foreach($data as $key=>$value){
       $valueArray = explode(",",$value);
       foreach($valueArray as $index=>$path){
          $sql = "INSERT INTO `pay_slips`(`paye_id`, `trade_id`, `inv_pdf`, `created_date`, `created_by`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '".$com_name."','".$path."',NOW(),'".$_SESSION['email']."')";
          $response = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          if(!$response){
             // Insertion Failed
          }
       }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do make some breakpoint on the line after you loop $data on foreach. You can `var_dump` it and see the structur, seeing this line
`$shareArray[$shK] = $shVal;`
I doubt your data is actually an array that could be used this way `'".$valueshar['paye_path']."'`

Maybe give some clarity on explanation by creating breakpoint on each line to make sure the data structure is correct. Also because the return statement inside the loop your function will stop prematurely if it need to process more than 1 child array.

Comment: how to change `Array ( [0] => 2017.pdf,25021.pdf,6940178.pdf,)` to `Array ( [0] => 2017.pdf,[1] => 25021.pdf,[2] =>6940178.pdf,) `

Comment: on var_dump $data getting this `array(1) { [0]=> string(144) "2886815291529493312789dbc5e8bbc27c48b5892130a6650f7.pdf,485206316152949331215934afa38db134c80f2444e07734a3f.pdf,4805235611529493312169512017.pdf" }`

Comment: to change `Array ( [0] => 2017.pdf,25021.pdf,6940178.pdf,)` to separated format you could use something like `$data = explode(',', $data[0])` if you are perfectly sure that it will enter key 0.

Comment: I think you just need to format input data to needed format, so playing arround with the string will be enough. Please do read on `explode()`, 'implode()' to format array. After getting the proper array format you could just implode the formated arrray field when doing insert with 1 statement using implode. You could try something like `$dataToBeInserted['paye_id'] = $paye_id; $dataToBeInserted['trade_id'] = $trade_id;` and have php version of structured field ready to be inserted.

Comment: your explode is working great but in foreach loop only last file is there not all files are coming in foreach . and how to insert  [0]=>file1   in first row, then [1]=> file2 in second row in db

Comment: Just loop through them and do insert on each value. Do return after **all** value have been inserted.